# App Engine SDK DevServer Read-Only Mode?

Tags: google-app-engine

Is there a way to run the app engine dev server in read-only mode in order to simulate the scheduled maintenance by Google which puts the datastore into read-only mode?

[Gracefully Degrading During Scheduled Maintenance](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/howto/maintenance.html)

Comment: +1: interesting question!  Maybe file an "issue" with the GAE issue tracker?

Comment: A very astute observation. Perhaps Nick Johnson will take notice of this and help get this fast-tracked? Please?

Comment: There is GAE issue #1811:  Allow user admins to disable capabilities for testing, which is pretty much asking for the same thing and it doesn't look like there is a solution yet. Hopefully, Google will make this a priority.

Comment: In the past, I have turned directories read only to help diagnose issues where a system is writing to a folder that will be read only in production. I am not sure if GAE developer uses local disk for storage. If so, changing those folders and contents to read only for a little while might prove interesting. Then again, it may be an unexpected condition and GAE might choke. Worth a try though.

Answer (score 2):

I wish there was a checkbox that would make the datastore read-only. This hack seems to do what I need. Put the following in your main handler:

```
from google.appengine.runtime.apiproxy_errors import CapabilityDisabledError
from google.appengine.api import apiproxy_stub_map

def make_datastore_readonly():
  """Throw ReadOnlyError on put and delete operations."""
  def hook(service, call, request, response):
    assert(service == 'datastore_v3')
    if call in ('Put', 'Delete'):
      raise CapabilityDisabledError('Datastore is in read-only mode')
  apiproxy_stub_map.apiproxy.GetPreCallHooks().Push('readonly_datastore', hook, 'datastore_v3')

def main():
  make_datastore_readonly()
```

It was found here:
http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine/msg/51db9d51401715ca

Comment: Looks like a good solution but I haven't tested it yet.  

Nick Johnson recently made a post about this issue: http://blog.notdot.net/2010/03/Handling-downtime-The-capabilities-API-and-testing

He goes deeper into the Capabilities API uses that for the hooks.