# AppEngine/Python: Why isn't the exception caught?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, try-catch, wsgi

I'm trying to write a Google-Appengine app that will fail nicely when datastore writes are disabled

Currently my main() looks like this:

```
def main():
    make_datastore_readonly()
    try:
        run_wsgi_app(application)
    except CapabilityDisabledError:
        run_wsgi_app(NoWrite)
```

---

If I set main to:

```
def main():
    run_wsgi_app(application)
```

My app displays a traceback when the exception is raised.

---

If I set main to:

```
def main():
    run_wsgi_app(NoWrite)
```

It will properly show my error message (although for every request).

---

Getting back to my modified version of main, this one:

```
def main():
    make_datastore_readonly()
    try:
        run_wsgi_app(application)
    except CapabilityDisabledError:
        run_wsgi_app(NoWrite)
```

Instead of getting my error message, I still get a traceback that looks like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/webapp/_webapp25.py", line 703, in __call__
    handler.post(*groups)
  File "/Users/kevin/Sche/main.py", line 232, in post
    me.put();
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/db/__init__.py", line 1074, in put
    return datastore.Put(self._entity, **kwargs)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/datastore.py", line 579, in Put
    return PutAsync(entities, **kwargs).get_result()
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/datastore.py", line 556, in PutAsync
    return _GetConnection().async_put(config, entities, local_extra_hook)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/datastore/datastore_rpc.py", line 1553, in async_put
    return make_put_call(base_req, pbs, extra_hook)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/datastore/datastore_rpc.py", line 1543, in make_put_call
    self.__put_hook, user_data)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/datastore/datastore_rpc.py", line 1188, in make_rpc_call
    rpc.make_call(method, request, response, get_result_hook, user_data)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 519, in make_call
    self.__service, method, request, response, self.__rpc)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 207, in Call
    function(service, call, request, response)
  File "/Users/kevin/Sche/main.py", line 18, in hook
    raise CapabilityDisabledError('Datastore is in read-only mode')
CapabilityDisabledError: Datastore is in read-only mode
```

So, my question is, why isn't the exception caught?

Edit:

This function is from [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2283824/app-engine-sdk-devserver-read-only-mode)

```
def make_datastore_readonly():
  """Throw ReadOnlyError on put and delete operations."""
  def hook(service, call, request, response):
    assert(service == 'datastore_v3')
    if call in ('Put', 'Delete'):
      raise CapabilityDisabledError('Datastore is in read-only mode') //Line 18
  apiproxy_stub_map.apiproxy.GetPreCallHooks().Push('readonly_datastore', hook, 'datastore_v3')
```

Comment: ... `main()` isn't even in the traceback!

Comment: @DmitryBeransky Line 18 is part of make_datastore_readonly(), a function that makes the datastore readonly. I need to execute it because I'm on a development server and thats the only way to simulate a read-only datastore.

Comment: I'm guessing run_wsgi_app catches the exception and prints out a stacktrace.

Comment: @dragonx So is there no easy way to handle the exception for all pages? or do I have to check to see if that exception was raised on every single page's class?

Comment: I was going to suggest the same thing as lucemia, handle the exception in a base class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `main` function only register this application. Therefore, the exception will not raise in the main function. Therefore the `try ... catch` statement won't work.

The way to handle this exception is defining a new RequestHandler. Then, all requests which want to have this feature should inherent from the new RequestHandler.

### for example:

```
Class MyRequestHandler(RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        try:
            self.get_handler()
        except CapabilityDisabledError:
            pass

class MyRequest(MyRequestHandler):
    def get_handler(self):
        # ....
        pass
```

Comment: Perfect, that's what I'll end up doing.